# dot net core 2.1 custom identity middleware. No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultForbidScheme found

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

Migrated our app from .net core 1.1 to 2.1

Controllers use `Authorize` attribute:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

In Startup.cs add additional middleware (ConfigureServices and Configure methods provided):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOptions();
    services.Configure<WebSectionConfigModel>(Configuration.GetSection("Web"));
    services.AddDbContext<MessagingContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("messagingConnection")), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
    services.AddTransient(/*...*/);
    services.AddSingleton(/*...*/);

    services.AddSignalR(/* ... */);

   services.AddMvc()
       .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

   services.AddAuthentication(options =>
   {
       options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Anonymous";
       options.DefaultForbidScheme = "Anonymous";
   });

   services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(/*...*/);

   services.AddAutoMapper();
}


 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
 {
     loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug);
     loggerFactory.AddDebug();
     loggerFactory.AddNLog();

     app.UseStaticFiles();

     app.UseCors(policyBuilder =>
     {
         /*...*/
     });


     app.UseMiddleware<CustomIdentityMiddleWare>();
     app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ErrorHandlingMiddleware));

     app.UseWebSockets();
     app.UseSignalR(routes =>
     {
         routes.MapHub<MessagesHub>("/messageshub");
     });

     app.UseMvc(Router.GetRouter);
 }
```

In CustomIdentityMiddleWare.cs code i create Custom identity:

```
public class CustomIdentityMiddleWare
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    /* ... ctor and other method ... */

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        /* ... */
        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new CustomIdentity(claims, id, "Custom");

        ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
        context.User = claimsPrincipal;
        await _next(context);

        /* ... */
    }
}
```

CustomIdentity code:

```
public class CustomIdentity : ClaimsIdentity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public CustomIdentity(IEnumerable<Claim> claims, Guid Id, string authenticationType) : base(claims, authenticationType)
    {
        this.Id = Id;
    }
}
```

In .net core version 1.1 all works fine. 
But in 2.1 version I started getting an error message:

> 2018-06-26 14:11:05.6088|ERROR|Message: No authenticationScheme was
>   specified, and there was no DefaultForbidScheme found. StackTrace:
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ForbidAsync(HttpContext
>   context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ForbidResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAlwaysRunResultFilters()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext)    at
>   messaging.moex.com_v2.Infrastructure.ErrorHandlingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)

I understand that i should configure AddAuthentication somehow, but don't know exactly how.

Tried this code, but with no luck:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Anonymous";
    options.DefaultForbidScheme = "Anonymous";
});
```

Comment: Can you show whole startup? The order of adding services is relevant...

Comment: @Stephu ConfigureServices and Configure code methods provided

Comment: @aleha - did you manage to resolve this in the end?